# How to use: while not in

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to check if a list has no member as boolean operator AND, OR, NOT.

I use:

```
while ('AND' and 'OR' and 'NOT') not in list:
  print 'No boolean operator'
```

However, when my input is: `a1 c2 OR c3 AND`, it prints 'No boolean operator', which means this list is considered no boolean operator in it by using above loop sentence.

Hope somebody can help to correct.

Thanks,
Cindy

Comment: Why are you using `while` instead of `if`? And please don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 7):

**Using `sets` will be screaming fast if you have any volume of data**

If you are willing to use sets, you have the `isdisjoint()` method which will check to see if the intersection between your operator list and your other list is empty.

```
MyOper = set(['AND', 'OR', 'NOT'])
MyList = set(['c1', 'c2', 'NOT', 'c3'])

while not MyList.isdisjoint(MyOper):
    print "No boolean Operator"
```

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint

Answer (score 4):

The expression `'AND' and 'OR' and 'NOT'` always evaluates to `'NOT'`, so you are effectively doing

```
while 'NOT' not in some_list:
    print 'No boolean operator'
```

You can either check separately for all of them

```
while ('AND' not in some_list and 
       'OR' not in some_list and 
       'NOT' not in some_list):
    # whatever
```

or use sets

```
s = set(["AND", "OR", "NOT"])
while not s.intersection(some_list):
    # whatever
```

Comment: Isn't there a missing "not" in the intersection example?

Answer (score 3):

`and`ing strings does not do what you think it does - use any to check if any of the strings are in the list:

```
while not any(word in list_of_words for word in ['AND', 'OR', 'NOT']):
    print 'No boolean'
```

Also, if you want a simple check, an `if` might be better suited than a `while`...

Comment: It's worth noting that this might scan through the list_of_words three times (once for every word it looks for). In most cases this is probably not a problem, but good to keep in mind if list_of_words grows large.

Comment: @pafcu Three scans are done only if the first word AND and the second word OR are not in the list_of_words. In other cases, 1 or 2 scans will be sufficient. Personally, I find clearer if the word 'word' isn't used to iterate in ['AND', 'OR', 'NOT']. I prefer to read any(andornot in list_of_words for andornot in ('AND', 'OR', 'NOT')) .

Answer (score 2):

The expression `('AND' and 'OR' and 'NOT')` evaluates to `'NOT'`, so you are testing whether the list has NOT or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
while not any( x in ('AND','OR','NOT') for x in list)
```

EDIT:

thank you for the upvotes , but etarion's solution is better since it tests if the words AND, OR, NOT are in the list, that is to say 3 tests.

Mine does as many tests as there are words in list.

EDIT2:

Also there is

```
while not ('AND' in list,'OR' in list,'NOT' in list)==(False,False,False)
```

Comment: Each of the 3 tests in entarions solution look at each item in the list, so it takes `3*len(lst)` tests too. Your solution looks n times at 3 element, so it does `len(lst)*3` tests. But I like this better because it performs the same no matter which of the `('AND','OR','NOT')` is in the list, while entarions answer performs best if 'AND' is in the list and worse if it's 'NOT'. Not that any of this makes a big difference ...

Comment: Btw, your edit2 performs worst, since it always does all 3n tests even if a match has been found before.

Comment: @ Jochen Ritzel On Edit2, you're right. For Edit1, it's in fact undecidable: my solution is better if one of the 3 is in the beginning of the list, and worse if there is one of the 3 only at the end of the list. All depends on the structure of the list. There is an advantage in etarion's solution: depending on what he may know concerning the list, he may choose to use w in ('AND','OR','NOT) or w in ('OR','NOT','AND') according the list's nature; while in mine, it isn't useful to change the order in ('AND','OR','NOT'). But my solution seems mentally clearer for me, I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `('AND' and 'OR' and 'NOT')` evaluates to `"NOT"`, which may or may not be in your list...

```
while 'AND' not in MyList and 'OR' not in MyList and 'NOT' not in MyList:
    print 'No Boolean Operator'
```

Comment: it doesn't evaluate to true, it evaluates to 'NOT', a minor point!

Comment: Gaa... Too much switching between languages.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you are looking for something like this:

```
>>> s = "a1 c2 OR c3 AND"
>>> boolops = ["AND", "OR", "NOT"]
>>> if not any(boolop in s for boolop in boolops):
...     print "no boolean operator"
... 
>>> s = "test"
>>> if not any(boolop in s for boolop in boolops):
...     print "no boolean operator"
... 
no boolean operator
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works.

This bit `('AND' and 'OR' and 'NOT')` will evaluate as `'NOT'`. So your code is equivalent to::

while not 'NOT' in list:
  print 'No boolean operator'

You could try this:

while not set('AND' and 'OR' and 'NOT').union(list):
   print 'No boolean operator'

Comment: That won't work: set('AND' and 'OR' and 'NOT') is set(['N','O','T']), the union of that with the list is nonempty, so it's True, not True is False, so it'll never be executed.